# failed to separate return object with SIFNE

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I want to build a simple array data wrapper. It shows me a data what I suggested views (like double or character).

This function `get_type()` simply returns separate objects with `enum` tags (I used SIFNE).

So my expectation was, if some pointer (`void* tmp`) existed, when I call `get_type<CHARACTER>(tmp, size)` then function would return an `arrayview<char>` object.

But it isn't, it raises an error:

> c2440 ' function-style-cast ' cannot convert from 'initializer list' to

This is my full code of my test code (I simplified my problem):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class test_array_type {
    CHARACTER,
    DOUBLE
};


template<typename T>
class arrayview {
    // yeah, you might think that why this class is needed, 
    // I removed many member methods. 
public:
    T* m_data;
    const int m_size;
    arrayview(T* data, int size) :m_data(data), m_size(size) {};
};

template<test_array_type T>
struct testType {
    using type = typename arrayview<double>;
};

template<>
struct testType<test_array_type::CHARACTER> {
    using type = typename arrayview<char>;
};

template<test_array_type ty>
testType<ty>::type get_type(void* tmp) {
    switch (ty) {
        case test_array_type::CHARACTER:
            return testType<test_array_type::CHARACTER>::type(tmp, 10);
        case test_array_type::DOUBLE:
            return testType<test_array_type::DOUBLE>::type(tmp, 10);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* tmp = new char[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tmp[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
    tmp[9] = '\0';
    testType<test_array_type::CHARACTER>::type ttt = get_type< test_array_type::CHARACTER>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(tmp));
    testType<test_array_type::CHARACTER>::type(tmp, 10);
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(ttt.m_data) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

If I remove all constructors except the default constructor, then it compiles. But that's not I want to make.

I think I misunderstand how the compiler and template rules and principles work.

Comment: _"cannot convert from 'initializer list' to"_ - Always show the full error message (unless it's a huge chunk of many errors, then only show the first few errors).

Answer (score 1):

What is SIFNE? Did you mean [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error)? There is no SFINAE in your code.

Your `get_type()` method is trying to `return` two *unrelated* types based on an `enum`, but you can't do that in C++.

Instead of using a `switch`, you should use either:

- [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) (C++17 and later):

```
template<test_array_type ty>
auto get_type(void* tmp) {

    if constexpr (ty == test_array_type::CHARACTER) {
        return testType<test_array_type::CHARACTER>::type{tmp, 10};
    } else {
        return testType<test_array_type::DOUBLE>::type{tmp, 10};
    }

    // or simply:
    // return testType<ty>::type{tmp, 10};
}
```

- [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

```
template<test_array_type ty>
void get_type(void*) {}

template<>
arrayview<char> get_type<test_array_type::CHARACTER>(void* tmp) {
    return arrayview<char>{tmp, 10};
}

template<>
arrayview<double> get_type<test_array_type::DOUBLE>(void* tmp) {
    return arrayview<double>{tmp, 10};
}
```

Comment: thank you. the solution was using ```if constexpr```. by the way, @RemyLebeau. I understand it. But why the  use  {tmp, 10}, instead of (tmp, 10 ) constructor. I didn't make initilize-list constructor?

Comment: @fabyday do a search for "C++ Uniform Initialization" and "C++ List Initialization", they'll explain the syntax and reasoning